# Is it OK to override MarshalByRefObject#Equals?

Tags: c#, appdomain, marshalbyrefobject

The documentation for [`MarshalByRefObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.marshalbyrefobject?view=netframework-4.7.2) states,

> When you derive an object from `MarshalByRefObject` for use across application domain boundaries, you should not override any of its members, nor should you call its methods directly.

Does this warning apply to inherited methods, specifically `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, or only to methods added by `MarshalByRefObject`?

Comment: I'd assume `Equals` and `GetHashCode` don't apply, as `MarshalByRefObject` doesn't override those, as you can see here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/marshalbyrefobject.cs,8ec9f4cbed5b7726

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree with @CamiloTerevinto on that, I wonder if object reference equality is important. Of course the bigger question is, why are you still using this 'legacy' technology?

Comment: @DavidG I haven't been able to find any documentation about that, that's why I commented, but I haven't used Remoting.

Comment: @DavidG I'm not still using it, I was going to start. I've been reading tutorials about how to unload AppDomains to allow users to reload plugins without restarting an application, and this is what they say to use.